# need to change the font for class members in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

how to change the font for members from italic to normal? please see the picture.
[image]

Comment: Just so it's clear, which member are you trying to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it would be under Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of options in `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring`. If you expand the `Java` option to the right you'll see several predefined elements you can configure.